# Difference between どれだけ and どのくらい and どんなに

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, nuances

It seems that どれだけ can be used interchangeably with どのくらい and どんなに, but is there any difference in nuance?

For example:

- (どれだけ/どんなに)聞いても意味が分からない
- (どれだけ/どんなに)説明しても、あの人はわかってくれない

- 彼の身長は(どれだけ/どのくらい)ですか。
- 銀行に(どれだけ/どのくらい)お金がありますか。

Does the meaning change at all if you use one over the other?